# MySQL Select using WHERE, LIKE, OR and AND

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to search a customer database by either their company name or customer name (first and last name). But I also need to search dependant on whether they're active/inactive/deleted too. But my query seems to be ignoring the last 1 or 2 `AND` statements.

Here's what I have so far:

```
    if($type == 'deleted') {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `".self::$table_name."` 
        WHERE `company_name` LIKE '%{$id}%' 
        OR CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) LIKE '%{$id}%'
        AND `deleted` = '1'";
    } elseif($type == 'inactive') {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `".self::$table_name."`
        WHERE `company_name` LIKE '%{$id}%' 
        OR CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) LIKE '%{$id}%'
        AND `deleted` = '0' AND `status` = 'inactive'";
    } else {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `".self::$table_name."`
        WHERE `company_name` LIKE '%{$id}%'
        OR CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) LIKE '%{$id}%'
        AND `status` = 'active' AND `deleted` = '0'";
    }
```

I pass through a type, which is either active, inactive, or deleted. It will default to active if nothing is passed through. However, because I need to search company name, or the CONCAT of first and last name, it appears to be ignoring the last few AND statements.

When I search for inactive, it brings a few results but includes active/inactive/deleted results. Where am I going wrong? I know it has to be something to do with the OR, but how can I get around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if($type == 'deleted') {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `".self::$table_name."` WHERE ( `company_name` LIKE '%{$id}%' OR CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) LIKE '%{$id}%' ) AND `deleted` = '1'";
    } elseif($type == 'inactive') {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `".self::$table_name."` WHERE ( `company_name` LIKE '%{$id}%' OR CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) LIKE '%{$id}%' ) AND `deleted` = '0' AND `status` = 'inactive'";
    } else {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `".self::$table_name."` WHERE ( `company_name` LIKE '%{$id}%' OR CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) LIKE '%{$id}%' ) AND `status` = 'active' AND `deleted` = '0'";
    }
```

PUT the OR condition inside () followed by AND statements.